# Resizing image to fit the display with CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

Using web responsive design I want to put a big image as background on the frontpage, which always stays 100% width and height. Very similar to https://ghost.org

Here is how I'm trying to do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jp5AQ/1144/

```
div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    outline: solid 1px red;
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly. The image is disturbed by resizing the window.

Comment: Check it with a browser inspection tool. Are you sure the rule is not overlapped by another one?

Comment: like ghost.org, use a background image and a background-sizing attribute like: background-size: cover; to keep the aspect ratio. If you set width and height of an image it will try to fulfill these rules and disregarding the aspect ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with pure CSS you can use the CSS3 `background-size` property:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(your-image.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a fiddle demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jp5AQ/1149/

This is the same technique used on the Ghost site you gave as a reference.

Note that I've given the `html` and `body` elements `height:100%` so that the `div` stretches to fill the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<img />` tag.

Call the image through CSS and use `background-size: cover;`.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jp5AQ/1147/)

Answer (score 1):

try this css:

```
.banner-bg { 
    background-image: url(../images/header-bannerbg.png); 
    background-position: fixed; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    height: 580px; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;  
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aashi/Jp5AQ/1146/

Answer (score 1):

Your image will always be the max-width of the browser window; however, the height will not stay at 100% of the browser window because the image on the screen needs to stay in proportion with the original image. As the width of the browser window shrinks, so will the height.Otherwise your image would be skewed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `background: cover`.
The post maybe be helpful http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to do that with an img tag.

it will work a lot better with:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jp5AQ/1145/) of it

Answer (score 1):

just remove the image inserted with an image tag and instead put the image in a div as background.

div: should get height and width of window screen size (most likely with javascript)

insert image with the css style:

`div{
    background: url(path_to_img/img.jpeg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; // you also can use cover, just look how you wish the picture should be cut or not. for background-size you also need some prefix for some browsers
}`

here is the link for css background: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

and here is the link for background-size : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp